# Shallow render component and scryRenderedComponentsWithType

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been playing with `reactjs` `TestUtils`. It's been pretty frustrating. I'm not sure but after experimenting for hours. It seems to me that after shallow rendering a component, I can't use `findRenderedComponentWithType` or `scryRenderedComponentsWithType`. In fact, I'm not sure how to extract the object out by its type from the `ReactComponent tree`. I'm not sure why as I am pretty new to `reactjs` and I'm not sure what I can or cannot do.

example:

```
var Layout = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        console.log(this.props);
        return (
            <div id="data-trader">
                <header className="header">
                    <LogoElement />
                    <UserMenu user={this.props.user} />
                </header>
                <div className="container max">
                    <div className="main">
                        <RouteHandler path={ this.props.path } query={ this.props.query } params={ this.props.params } user={this.props.user} />
                    </div>
                    <Footer />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Tests:

```
describe('Shallow Layout', function(){
    beforeEach(function(){
        fakeDOM = TestUtils.createRenderer();
    });

    // PASS    
    it('should exist as a component', function(done){
        expect(<Layout/>).to.exist;
        done();
    });

    // PASS
    it('should have id=data-trader', function(done){
        fakeDOM.render(<Layout />);
        component = fakeDOM.getRenderOutput();

        expect(component.props.id).to.eql('data-trader');
        done();
    });

    it('get children', function(done) {
        var StubbedComponent = TestHelpers.stubRouterContext(component);
        var k = TestUtils.findRenderedComponentWithType(StubbedComponent, UserMenu);
        console.log(k.length);
        done();
    })
});
```

I get this error with `findRenderedComponentWithType`

```
Error: Did not find exactly one match for componentType:function UserMenu()
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and after going through the code I found the issue is that scry/find call findAllInRenderedTree and test for a DOM element:

https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/test/ReactTestUtils.js#L48 and https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/test/ReactTestUtils.js#L62

given that both tests returns false, the method is returning an empty array. (which cause the error you describe in find, and cause scry to return an empty array).

I think this is caused because the output of shallowRender is NOT a DOM element (that's why shallowRendere is great :).

If you want to find the first children of a shallowRendered tree of certain type, you can do something like this:

```
  findChildrenOfType (view, Component) {
    if (!view) return null;

    if (reactTestUtils.isElementOfType(view, Component)) return view;

    if (view.length) { // is an Array
      for (let i = 0; i < view.length; i++) {
        let found = this.findChildrenOfType(view[i], Component);
        if (found) return found;
      }
    } else {
      if (!view.props || !view.props.children) return null;
      let children = view.props.children;

      return this.findChildrenOfType(children, Component);
    }
  }
```

hope this helps!